# How to convert a C# sorted dictionary to a related javascript key Value pair array

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a sorted Dictionary.When selecting an option from the dropdown, I want to get the id of the selected element(these option ids are also the keys of the sorted dictionary) and access the particular value(which is an Employee object) of the sorted dictionary,take out the needed value and put that value in empDesig textbox. Since this task is done using javascript and razor doesn'tt support javascript,I cannot figure out a way to do this.

My code:

```
  @model SortedDictionary<int, HelloWorldMvcApp.Employee>

    <div>
    <select class="empNameDropdown" id="empNameDropdown" >
           <option>Select Name</option>                      
         @foreach(HelloWorldMvcApp.Employee  emp in @Model.Values){              
          <option id="@emp.EmployeeId" class="empOption">@emp.Name</option>                  
         }                               
    </select>   
     @Html.Label("Designation")
     <br/>
     @Html.TextBox("empDesig","");
     <br/><br/>                
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){                  
        $("#empNameDropdown").on('change', function () {
            var id=$(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');           
            $("#empDesig").val("@Model[id].designation");                   
        });
    });                 
</script>
```

The javascript variable **Id** cannot be used in razor.I want to use this Id value to get the relevant object from the sorted dictionary. Are there any ways? please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your this line

```
 $("#empDesig").val("@Model[id].designation");
```

does not work the way you expect! Here `id` is  a javascript variable and the part of the line which starts with `@` prefix is C#. You cannot mix C# code inside javascript like that. Remember, C# code executes in server and javascript code executes later in browser. The browser cannot execute C# code! It can execute javascript code using its' javascript engine.

What you should do is, create a js variable and store your view's page mdoel to that and access that as needed. You can use a  the `SerializeObject` method along with `Html.Raw` to do that (inside the script section of a razor view).

```
var dict = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
```

So basically this will create a js object representing your sorted dictionary and set to the `dict` js variable. It will look something like this, for a dictionary of 2 items.

```
{
    "11": {
        "EmployeeId": 101,
        "Name": "Scott",
        "designation": "Manager"
    },
    "12": {
        "EmployeeId": 102,
        "Name": "John",
        "designation": "Developer"
    }
}
```

Now before we go any further with scripts, let's fix an issue with the markup. You should set the `value` attribute of the Select options.

```
<select class="empNameDropdown" id="empNameDropdown" >
    <option>Select Name</option> 
    @foreach(HomeController.Employee  emp in @Model.Values){              
        <option value="@emp.EmployeeId" class="empOption">@emp.Name</option> 
    }                               
</select>
```

Now when the `change` event happens on the select element. you can call `$(this).val()` and it will give you the value of the selected option. Once you get the value, all you have to do is, search our `dict` js object and get the sub property (for the selected employee) and get the needed property value (designation ?)

Also make sure to include your page level scripts which uses jQuery only after jQuery is loaded to the page ( You may put that in a Scripts section, assuming you have the script block to include jQuery library defined **before** calling the Scripts section)

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dict = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
        console.log(dict);  // Check your browser console now
        // Or even see the stringified version of the object
        console.log(JSON.stringify(dict));  

        function getEmployee(id) {
            for (var key in dict) {
                if (dict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    if (dict[key] && dict[key].EmployeeId === id) {
                        return dict[key];
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#empNameDropdown").on('change', function() {
                var id = $(this).val();
                var employee = getEmployee(parseInt(id));
                if (employee) {
                    $("#empDesig").val(employee.designation);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

You have not mentioned what is the key of the sorted dictionary items. If it is same as the `employeeId` property value of each item,  you can fix the if condition inside the  line `if (dict[key] && dict[key].EmployeeId === id) {` to simply check  whether `key` is equal to `id`

Comment: Thank  very much! you are a life savior! :) :)